Unable to Update Live Activities in Background and Lock Screen Using FCM Push Notifications in Flutter
I'm working on a Flutter application that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send push notifications. I want to update live activities whenever I receive a push notification, but I'm facing an issue where the live activities are not updating when the app is in the background or on the lock screen.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
  final notification = message.notification;
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    final _liveActivitiesPlugin = LiveActivities();
    _liveActivitiesPlugin.init(appGroupId: "group.new_activity");

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? activityId = prefs.getString('liveActivityId');

    if (activityId != null) {
      await _liveActivitiesPlugin.updateActivity(
        activityId,
        {'soc': '${++soc}'},
      );
    }
  }


int soc = 0;
Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('Title: ${message.notification?.title}');
  print('body: ${message.notification?.body}');
  print('Payload: ${message.data}');
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    final _liveActivitiesPlugin = LiveActivities();
    _liveActivitiesPlugin.init(appGroupId: "group.new_activity");
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? activityId = prefs.getString('liveActivityId');
    if (activityId != null) {
      await _liveActivitiesPlugin.updateActivity(
        activityId,
        {'soc': '${++soc}'},
      );
    }
  }
}

Problem:
I am trying to update the live activities using FCM push notifications, but it is not updating when the app is in the background or on the lock screen.
